# Formatting sandbox — please test stuff here

Tags: discussion, formatting

This post is provided so that people can, in the answers and comments below, test formatting features of Expats Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**/Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

<sub>See [*Which sites have YouTube embedding on?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462)</sub>